# Database agnostic query to select top 1 or top n rows?

Tags: sql

I have a table with no PK column. I am not supposed to change that. There is also a numeric column which can be used to order the rows. How do i select the top 1 or top n rows without using any function, ie a database agnostic query ?

I looked at this query, but it does not work for my case - 
[Can there be a database-agnostic SQL query to fetch top N rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824931/can-there-be-a-database-agnostic-sql-query-to-fetch-top-n-rows)

Comment: You can use the (ANSI standard SQL) `ORDER BY someColumn OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;` but it's not supported by all DBMS.

Comment: @ypercube - as an aside, was wondering if we could have one SUPER SQL platform and SUPER SQL language which would serve as a front end to all RDBMS. You can use one language to query all DBs...and that too DBs of different brands. Does such a thing exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the thread you linked to, there isn't much of a database agnostic solution:

- DB2 -- `select * from table order by col fetch first 10 rows only`
- Informix -- `select first 10 * from table order by col`
- Microsoft SQL Server and Access -- `select top 10 * from table order by col`
- MySQL and PostgreSQL -- `select * from table order by col limit 10`
- Oracle 8i -- `select * from (select * from table order by col) where rownum <= 10`

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,4515,4678

Comment: How do I also do an order by some column in each of the above queries ? I think that is a must when we use top or top-like query. Without it, the above queries are partially useful. In SQL server, just add an order by column after the from. what about the others ?

Comment: @sequel.learner: the same for the others. (see ypercube's edit)

Comment: @Denis: Postgres (from 8.4) and SQL-Server (2012 version) support the `OFFSET / FETCH` syntax.

Comment: @sequel.learner: I wouldn't know. I haven't used Oracle in years. :-P More seriously, certainly yes, for backwards compatibility reasons.